# jQuery UI loading flick

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I'm creating an ASP.NET MVC 3 application and changed the default project structure to load scripts on the end of the HTML, since this is a good practice.
Created the sections and successfully loaded the scripts in the correct order.

One of them, sets the jQuery UI. The scripts at the end of the Layout page looks like this:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/customappscript.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

But I have a problem to load some pages via AJAX. When the page is loading I can clearly see the default HTML button and after a few miliseconds the jQuery UI runs and sets the button style.
I think there is a way to fix this by loading first and then displaying. Maybe setting all buttons hidden and showing when UI is loaded, dunno.

Anyone has an idea on how to solve this?

Comment: If you have a huge page, it will load later. If you put your "hide" button in the customappscript.js it should load after jqueryui and essentially give the same result? You can take a look at IE Developers/Firebugs NET logging, to see why it loads so late, and which things might take too long.

Answer (score 0):

Such things happen when you have a very heavy page. The approach I use is to simply render the buttons hidden and after applying .button() make them visible.